# PHP How to create urls properly?

Tags: php, laravel, url

I have never understood how to create proper URLs. Every time I end up with trying to figure out if I should do *?var=value* or *&var=value* and then if *?var=value* already exists then I end up with *?var=value&var=value*.

P.S. I am working with Laravel. (*So maybe there is a built-in function?*)

**For example:**
I have pagination and my URL could look like this

```
www.example.com OR
www.example.com?name=John
```

Then my pagination link is *href="?page=2"* and I end up with

```
www.example.com?name=John?page=2
```

Then I want to navigate to the next page with *href="?page=3"* and I end up with this. Because it keeps on adding.

```
www.example.com?name=John?page=2?page=3
```

What a mess.... is there a function for PHP or Laravel that would create proper URLS? (knowing **when to use ? or &** and not add existing values all the time but **replace them if they exist already**.

Comment: Of course, I know that. So do I need to check every time if ? already exists?

Comment: You could use [`http_build_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Laravel I think you should use some helper functions:

```
route('user.profile', ['id' => 1]);
```

It will create url by route name and parameters, It will look like:
http://sitename/user/profile?id=1
And you can find some useful helper functions [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-url)

Answer (score 0):

There should be one and only `?` in URL's which separates URI and parameters, rest of the key-value pairs are separated by `&`, and if you need to pass `& or ?` as a parameter, then you need to [encode](https://www.urlencoder.org/) them.

you could pass an array to [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) and it will build the url for you

and in laravel there are [url helper](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#urls) functions you can use them with ease.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel come with a `route` helper which allow you to generage url quickly by passing the name with which you register your route.

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home.route')
```

Here you can see I pass **home.route** to the name method which is the name which I use for this route. And when I want to generate the URL for that route in my view I will juste do

```
{{ route('home.route') }}
```

If ny route take some parameters like this

```
Route::get('/person/{id}', 'HomeController@index')->name('home.route')
```

In view I will generate the url like this

```
{{ route('home.route', ['id' =>$id]) }}
```

Because you want juste to make pagination, Laravel comme with a buil in pagination. When you want to paginate something in your views, you must just call the  `paginate` function on your model and laravel will handle all the route for that. For example I you have a `Person` Model you can do that like this in your controller

```
$persons = Person::paginate(25)
```

And in your views to generate pagination for that you will have to do

```
{{ $persons->links() }}
```

And that's all